# show div not working with jquery and asp.net after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Before I ask this question I really searched in internet and all the answers talked about using update panel with jQuery, but my question more than simple. I'm trying to use jQuery with ASP.NET button and div as shown below, but it's not working or it's working but after the postback the page discard all the jQuery work.

```
    <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=btn1.ClientID %>").click(function () {
                $('#savediv').css('display', 'block');
            });
        })    
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="savediv"  style="display:none">
        <p>All Data Saved Successfully</p>
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Test" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it will postback, your clientside changes will be lost. So either use update panel or try to retain the state of your control throughout the postback.

Comment: Avoid using inline style; Try to create a classname for style and add&remove the class based on your condition/click event.

Comment: thank you @NileshThakkar for your answer You suggest that the Div is manipulated through code after postback event or i should use the update panel this is a long way to do simple think like show/hide div this point is not walfare the asp.net

Comment: thank you @JohnSmith for your answer, I'm not using inline style its just simple code to show my case and you too suggest to use code behind to solve problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try the below code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=btn1.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            $('#savediv').css('display', 'block');
             return false;
        });
    })    
</script>
```

Just add "return false;" to end of your button click's jquery code. It will prevent the button to post back.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this - No Need to Postback**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".AspButton").click(function () {
                $('#savediv').css('display', 'block');
            });
        })    
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="savediv"  style="display:none">
        <p>All Data Saved Successfully</p>
    </div>
    <asp:Button class='AspButton' ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Test" onclick="javascript:void(0)" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the difference between your answer and his questions code? will it not make postback?

Comment: <asp:Button class='AspButton' ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Test" />      class='AspButton'   $(".AspButton").click(function () {

Comment: does the above code not fire the postback event of button? my dear you have just added a class and firing the click event using class. but when click event fires then it will definitely fires the post back event

Comment: <asp:Button class='AspButton' ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Test" onclick="javascript:void(0)" />